# Overload stream operator for nested template C++ STL

Tags: c++, templates, stream, operator-overloading

I've got a data file that is a single line consisting of a nested series of doubles eg.

```
[[0.127279,0.763675,0.636396],[0.254558,0.890955,0.636396],
[0.127279,0.636396,0.763675],[0.254558,0.763675,0.763675],
[0.381838,0.890955,0.763675],[0.127279,0.509117,0.890955],
[0.254558,0.636396,0.890955],[0.509117,0.890955,0.890955]]
```

I'd like to be able to read this into a STL `vector<vector<double> >` using the stream operator which is templated across the inner type of A:

```
vector<vector<double> > A;
FIN >> A;
```

I've figured out a way to do this when the vector is not nested, ie. a simple `vector<T>` as so:

```
template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<T> &A){
  T x;
  string token; char blank;

  s >> blank; // Gobble the first '['
  while( getline(s, token, ',') ) {
   istringstream input(token);
   input >> x;
   A.push_back(x);
  }
  s >> blank; // Gobble the last ']'
  return s;
}
```

But I'm having problem with the `istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<vector<T> >&A)` part as I can't seem to catch the inner `]`'s properly. I'm sure that Boost has a way of doing this, but I'd like to see a solution with the STL for pedagogical purposes.

Note: I'm aware that overloading the stream operator for `vector<T>` can have far-reaching undesirable consequences and that the implementation should be wrapped up in its own class - I'm using this example above as it stands to clarify the question.

**EDIT:**
I'd like the method to be robust enough to handle a input array whose size (and inner array) size is *not* known in advance, but inferred from reading the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem with your code that you want to use the same function for both, when `T` is:

- `vector<double>`
- `double`

But the logic which needs to read the data into *vector* and *double* is slightly different. So you cannot do that, at least not with that simple logic:

I would prefer to write two functions, to handle both cases separately. After all, even in your case, the compiler will generate two different functions for each value of `T`.

```
template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<T> &A)
{
  T x;
  string token; char blank;

  s >> blank; // Gobble the first '['
  while( getline(s, token, ',') ) 
  {
   istringstream input(token);
   input >> x;
   A.push_back(x);
  }
// s >> blank; // Gobble the last ']'
  return s;
}

template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<vector<T>> &A)
{
  vector<T> x;
  string token; 
  char blank;

  s >> blank; // Gobble the first '['
  while( getline(s, token, ']') ) 
  {
   istringstream input(token);
   input >> x;
   s >> blank; //read , after [...]
   A.push_back(x);
   x.clear();
  }
  s >> blank; // Gobble the last ']'
  return s;
}
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
        vector<vector<double>> A;       
        cin >> A;
        for(size_t i = 0 ;i < A.size(); ++i)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0 ; j < A[i].size(); ++j)
                 cout << A[i][j] <<"   ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],[10,11,12],
[13,14,15],[16,17,18],
[19,20,21],[22,23,24]]
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   
4   5   6   
7   8   9   
10   11   12   
13   14   15   
16   17   18   
19   20   21   
22   23   24
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/iBbmw

Comment: This makes sense, I appreciate you using my own code in your example, it answers the question explicitly without introducing any extemporaneous details. Looking at it, it seems it should be able to handle any an arbitrary level of nested vectors!

Comment: @Hooked: `it should be able to handle any an arbitrary level of nested vectors!`... Yes, I think so. Btw, do you want to see boost solution?

Comment: For my own edification, absolutely! The question was asked for STL explicitly since Boost is not always installed as a standard configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example which is very simple.

- Read the whole line into a string.
- Replace all [ , ] and , with whitespace character.
- Create a simple stringstream with whitespace replaced string.

Now you can have a a simple loop of

```
double x;
while( stringstreamp >> x )
{
}
```

And some special logic after reading three doubles to insert them them into a new array.

Comment: This would work for the example above, but it seems rather fragile. If the size of the inner container changed, the method would fail. In addition, if the size of each inner container was a different size (which is certainly possible of a vector of vectors) then this method would have no way of knowing in advance when to start the new array.

Answer (score 1):

Some years later, and I was here struggling with the same problem.

Based on your contribution, I developed a modified version of the original template. This one is able to parse multidimensional arrays, even if they are spread across several lines.

```
template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<T> &A){
  while(true){
    T x;
    char c = s.peek();

    if( c == '[' || c == ','){ 
        s.ignore();
        if(s >> x) A.push_back(x);
        else throw invalid_argument("Bad, bad JS array!");
        continue;
    }

    if( c == ']') {
        s.ignore();
        return s;
    }

    /* Ignore line-break */
    s.ignore();     
  }
  return s;
}
```

Hope this can be useful for someone.